# MySQL connection remains after close(), with a thin wrapper

Tags: java, mysql

I wrote a Java program that connects to a MySQL database, immediately closes, and then sleeps for a while to terminate.

```
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(conn_str);
    conn.close();
    Thread.sleep(30 * 1000);
```

The above code works pretty fine. The *conn* will be closed immediately after calling close() and no connection appears during sleep().

After that, I wrote a thin connection wrapper:

```
    public static Connection CreateConnection(String _connectionStr) throws SQLException {
        Connection c = null;
        c = DriverManager.getConnection(_connectionStr);
        return c;
    }
```

the modified code is:

```
    Connection conn = ConnectionWrapper.CreateConnection(conn_str);
    conn.close();
    Thread.sleep(30 * 1000);
```

I expect these two have no difference, but with the latter case, the connection had been remain unclosed until the program terminates (here 30 seconds). This does not happen in the former code.

I checked the behavior with `mysqladmin extend-status | grep connected`, looking at the value of `Threads_connected`.

I want to use the latter wrapper for code abstraction. Please tell me if you have any idea of the behavior or workaround to close the connection forcibly.

Thanks,

--

Edited: fixed the "wrapper" code. It was my mistake.

Edited: The number of connections from mysqladmin is by default 1 (diagnostic one). The number becomes 2 while the latter code is running, while it is 2 with the former.

Comment: You have not created a wrapper. You have created a method that you call to get a connection (and neglected to respect the Java naming conventions while doing so). Both code snippets are strictly equivalent. Your diagnostic is probably wrong.

Comment: You are not actually calling the method `CreateConnection(ConnectionType, String)` directly. Are you doing something differently in the method `CreateConnection(String)` perhaps?

Comment: I believed both are equivalent but have different behaviors. I'm confused.

Comment: CreateConnection(String) is correct. I fixed the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

can you have a try on this codes... and see what will the error output...

```
try{
 con.close();
  if (con.isClosed()) 
    System.out.println("Connection closed.");
} catch (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException e) {
  System.err.println("ClassNotFoundException: " +e.getMessage());
} catch (SQLException e) {
  System.err.println("SQLException: " +e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: The code outputs "Connection closed." and no exception. isClosed() says the connection is closed, but the connection remains unclosed from `mysqladmin` command (and `netstat`) ...

Comment: Are you sure that the open connection is not your diagnostic one (created by mysqladmin when trying to get the status) ?

Comment: I'm sure on that. The number of connections is "1" I started monitoring and the connection increases.

Answer (score 0):

I think it  is connection pooling (a idea to save time on reconnects...)

Look into this article:

http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/connection_pooling_with_connectorj.html

Comment: I checked the article but I'm not sure my problem is related to the document. In the code above, I do the same with the code in the article, don't I?

Comment: Try to disable pooling and look again

Answer (score -2):

ok, sorry for being so numb looking at your code... as you can see... **you created a connection inside a method**... so it means when you get out of that method... you will not be able to close that connection(the variable c) because you just copied the connection on another variable by using a return(which is your variable conn)... and still the connection remains. **Try to create a class for your wrapper and not  a method**

Comment: Well,,,OK. Maybe I understand. It is similar to a problem of reference counting GC. I create a class. Thank you so much.

Comment: I agree with @JBNizet on this. You are able to close connections despite it being referenced from any number of other variables.

Comment: Oh, really? If so, why cannot I surely close the connection? isClose() says the connection has been closed but mysqladmin says the connection remains open, and when I increased the number of connections to test it reaches the upper limit of connections...